# texniccenter shortcut for user defined command

Tags: latex, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any chance to insert a "user defined command" in texniccenter by shortcut?

I want to insert a "user defined command" but all i found at the shortcut menu was to edit the shortcuts by shortcut. Even in the new Alpha version i didn't found any hint how to do that.

have someone an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Insert menu, then under "Own Text Modules" select Manage. You can add your own in there and then add the "Own Text Modules" to the shortcuts.

Comment: you can only add a shortcut to the first "Text Module" have you some idea how to select the other for shortcut?

Comment: No, I don't know how to make a shortcut directly to a custom script. I've just added the entire "Own Text Modules" to the editor context menu.

Answer (score 1):

J found a solution for this Problem, especially if you want to add e.g. `\bm{}` to an existing word or phrase.

First of all, define your "Own Text Module", for which you want to create a shortcut. Then, try to use this command with your keyboard (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>(x)</kbd>” where (x) is the number in front of your own text module within the menu.

For the german Version, it is (“<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>(x)</kbd>”). Remember this combination. Then assign this shortcut with the program `AutoHotkey`. The `AutoHotkey` script looks like this (for the german Version):

```
%%%
^b::Send !eb 6 
Return
%%%
```

This means: `^b(= <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>)` sends the command: `! (Alt)eb 6`

I had to add a space between `b` and `6`, however, otherwise it did not work.
It works great for me.